# Still Huge Memory usage for Python's json loads?

Tags: python, json, memory-leaks

Yes, this was asked seven years ago, but the 'answers' were not helpful in my opinion.  So much open data uses JSON, so I'm asking this again to see if any better techniques are available.  I'm loading a 28 MB JSON file (with 7,000 lines) and the memory used for json.loads is over 300 MB.

This statement is run repeatedly:
    `data_2_item =  json.loads(data_1_item)`

and is eating up the memory for the duration of the program.  I've tried various other statements such as `pd.read_json(in_file_name, lines=True)`
with the same results.  I've tried simplejson and rapidjson alternative packages also.

Comment: That's normal. Python objects are big. The JSON text `{}` is two bytes, but an empty Python dict is more like 240.

Comment: It has nothing to do with your JSON loader. Switching loaders won't help.

Comment: What do you want to do with contents ? only fee values, or processing all data ?

Comment: @themadmax   The Json data is to be loaded into a Pandas data frame.  From there it is sliced and diced many different ways.   The original Json data is from https://www.eia.gov/opendata/bulkfiles.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a commenter observed, json.loads is NOT the culprit. data_2_item can be very large -- sometimes 45K.  Since it is appended to a list over 7,000 times, the list becomes huge (300 MB) and that memory is NEVER released.  So to me, the answer:  no solution with existing packages/loaders.   The overall goal is to load a large JSON file into a Pandas Dataframe without using 300 MB (or more) of memory for intermediate processing.  And that memory does not shrink.  See also https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17048

Comment: In my experience, the dataframe memory estimates are grossly low when loading large JSON files that have arrays in the JSON objects. I have an example of a 28 MB JSON file loaded into a Pandas dataframe. The 'deep' memory usage displays 18 MB, however, the RSS memory consumed is nearly 300 MB. Python dictionaries and lists appear to have considerable overhead.

Answer (score 0):

If after loading your content you will be using only *part* of it then consider using [ijson](https://github.com/ICRAR/ijson) to load the JSON content in a streaming fashion, with low memory consumption, and only constructing the data you need to handle rather than the whole object.